# How does this foo function works?

Tags: c

This C program will take the value stored in the variable a and print them one by one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void foo(int n, int sum)
{
  int k = 0, j = 0;

  if (n == 0)
    return;

  k = n % 10;
  j = n / 10;

  sum = sum + k;

  foo (j, sum);

  printf ("%d, ", k);
}

int main ()
{
  int a = 2048, sum = 0;
  foo (a, sum);
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2, 0, 4, 8,
```

When the function foo executes:

1) For the first time: n = 2048, **k = 8**, j = 204, sum = 8

2) For the second time: n = 204, **k = 4**, j = 20, sum = 12

3) For the third time: n = 20, **k = 0**, j = 2, sum = 12

4) For the fourth time: n = 2, **k = 2**, j = 0, sum = 14

If I replace the line (present in the foo function):

```
printf ("%d, ", k);
```

with this:

```
printf ("%d | %d, ", k, sum);
```

Output:

```
2 | 14, 0 | 12, 4 | 12, 8 | 8,
```

Can someone please explain how this program works:

1) How it's printing value stored in **a**?

2) And in this order: 2, 0, 4, 8, ?

3) Why is the value of **sum** is changing when we're printing values of **k**?

4) What would happen when **n** become 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are calling the function `foo` on `a`.
2. That is the order since you are printing AFTER you are processing the rest of the number. Try moving the call to `printf` before the call to `foo` in `foo` and see if you get anything different.
3. `sum` is changing because you are doing `sum = sum + k` and passing it to all the future calls.
4. When `n` eventually becomes `0` due to repeated divisions, the last call to `foo` starts returning and following them all the previous calls start returning after printing the digit they had extracted using `n % 10`

Comment: Thanks for answering. If I move the call to `printf` above `foo` in `foo`, here's the output I'll get: `8, 4, 0, 2,` I'm sorry I still don't understand why I see the reversed output if I put the call to `printf` below `foo` in `foo`?

Comment: What you see here is a recursive function. Which means a function that calls itself. What the function does is first isolates a single digit out of `n` and calls itself again to process the rest. Thus subsequent calls isolate ` digit each, till `n` becomes 0. After that the functions start returning and before returning they print the digit they had isolated. The digits isolated will be `8`, `4`, `0` and `2` in that order. While printing since the last call would print first you get the order `2 0 4 8`

Comment: When you place the call to `printf` before `foo` you print the digit you isolated BEFORE you process the rest of the string ad hence you get the digit that was extracted first, first. Giving you 8 4 0 2.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!